# How to find all points within some circles in PostGIS

Tags: geometry, postgis

I've been given a array of center points(longitude and latitude) and corresponding radius,
and try to find all points in these circles.

I known how to find points in the specified circle (the center is (CPLng, CPLat), and radius is 3000m), using the below sql

```sql
SELECT l.*, ST_Distance(workplace_geom, ref_geom) as distance  
FROM locations AS l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_MakePoint(CPLng, CPLat)::geography AS ref_geom) AS r 
WHERE ST_DWithin(workplace_geom, ref_geom, 3000)
```

In order to get all point in series of circles, should I just union every set of points? or any other alternatives?

Comment: On a side note, coordinates should be expresses as longitude first, then latitude. Yours are swapped

Comment: there are several alternatives, but what should happen if a target point is close to several ref_geom?

Comment: @JGH coordinates are fixed. Thanks! The result returns to a set of points, so if a target point is close to several ref_geom, just returns the target point. Or remove duplicates in program.